# Zend Framework 2 - Use custom validators in input filter

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to use a custom validator with the input filter add method. I am using the latest version of the zend-validator package.

In my `module.config.php` I have this:

```
'validators' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'DoctrineRecordExists' => 'Utils\Validator\Doctrine\RecordExists',
        'NoDoctrineRecordExists' => 'Utils\Validator\Doctrine\NoRecordExists',
    ],
]
```

And I use it here:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'name',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => [
        [
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => [
                'min' => 3,
                'max' => 20,
            ],
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'NoDoctrineRecordExists',
            'options' => [
                'repository' => 'Account\Entity\OAuthUser',
                'field' => 'name',
                'entityManager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

But the constructor of NoRecordExists is never called. I get a 500 Error with no Exceptions available. If I remove the validator from the input filter, it works as expected.

I also tried this in my Module.php

```
public function getValidatorConfig() {
    return [
        'invokables' => [
            'DoctrineRecordExists' => 'Utils\Validator\Doctrine\RecordExists',
            'NoDoctrineRecordExists' => 'Utils\Validator\Doctrine\NoRecordExists',
        ],
    ];
}
```

But there was no difference.